# Print List without brackets in Dart

Tags: list, flutter, dart

I want to remove brackets "[]" from List while print in **Dart**.

**Code:**

```
void main() {

  var lst = new List(3); 
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    lst[i] = i;
  }

  print(lst);
}
```

**Current Output:**

```
[0, 1, 2]
```

**Expected Output:**

```
0, 1, 2
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you can use **join()** function to get your desired output

```
void main() {

  var lst = new List(3); 
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    lst[i] = i;
  }


  print(lst.join(", "));
}
```

Comment: you can accept any one's answer so that other user can see and prefer that answer

Comment: he needs `print(lst.join(', '));` as the items are separated by comma and space

Answer (score 3):

You can also achieve by replacing `[` and `]` by blank. Check below code,

```
void main() {

  var lst = new List(3); 
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    lst[i] = i;
  }

  print(lst.toString().replaceAll('[', '').replaceAll(']', ''));​
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
void main() {
  var lst = new List(3); 
  var output = "";
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    lst[i] = i;
    if (i == lst.length-1) {
       output = output + lst[i].toString();
    } else {
       output = output + lst[i].toString() + ", ";
    }
  }

  print(output);
}
```

Try the code in [Dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Its working but Jay Gadariya's solution is simple and short.

Answer (score 2):

I am facing similler problem something like
I have list of numbers:

```
List yourList = ["1","2","3"];
```

And want the out put like `1,2,3`

```
(yourList.toString().replaceAll("]","")).replaceAll("[","");
```

it gives me output as I want .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59420087/3235048

This is best way.

Comment: @SagarZala why is the best way? To do a for doesn't consume more resources that the replaceAll?

Comment: Best solution, made my day! But the last comma

Answer (score 0):

The methods above are outdated and not working anymore. The newer method for creating a list by using a constructor should look like this:

```
void main() {
  var lst = <int>[]; // creates an empty list with the int data type
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) { // for loop 3x
    lst.add(i); // adds the value of i to list
  }
  print(lst.join(", ")); // removes the brackes
}
```

The output is: 0, 1, 2