# How to remove Square brackets from output in dart language?

Tags: flutter, dart, insert, output

Remove the square bracket from the list. Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.

```
void main() {
  var digit = ["mian", "khan", "sami"];
  digit.insertAll(0, ['your', 'halako','dsfds']);
  print(digit); //[your, halako, dsfds, mian, khan, sami]
}
```

Comment: instead of image you must add code

Comment: check above on the read the lines you will understand.it give output like [your,halako etc]

Answer (score 0):

you can use join() function to get your desired output

you can try this code :

```
void main() {

var lst = new List(3); 
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
lst[i] = i;
}


print(lst.join(", "));
}
```

the original [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59420087/17170163)

**Edit**:

in your case Just replace the print with this and its work fine :

```
print(digit.join(", "));
```

Comment: check my program and make changes in it. Thank you

Comment: check the edit @MianSamiullah

Answer (score 0):

please try with this

```
void main() {
  var list = ["test", "test1"];
  String list1 = getWithoutBracket(list);
  print(list1);
}

String getWithoutBracket(var list) {
  String digit = "";

  if (list != null && list.isNotEmpty) {
    list.asMap().forEach((index, element) {
      digit += element;

      if (index != list.length - 1) {
        digit += ", ";
      }
    });
  }
  return digit;
}
```

output: test, test1

Comment: why you make a program very hard just remove the bracket from my program

Comment: here i didn't consider only your problem, I wrote this for all cases and one kind of generic

Comment: anyway thank you for taking your time I will try my best

Comment: lemme know does it work for your problem

Comment: List are being represented by brackets and values inside separated by commas... that's a global standard, I don't see what's the problem here.

Comment: sometimes we need to represent the list into the string that's why he would prefer to convert this list to a string.